# Properly evaluate a test dataset

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface-datasets

I trained a machine translation model using huggingface library:

```
def compute_metrics(eval_preds):
    preds, labels = eval_preds
    if isinstance(preds, tuple):
        preds = preds[0]
    decoded_preds = tokenizer.batch_decode(preds, skip_special_tokens=True)

    # Replace -100 in the labels as we can't decode them.
    labels = np.where(labels != -100, labels, tokenizer.pad_token_id)
    decoded_labels = tokenizer.batch_decode(labels, skip_special_tokens=True)

    # Some simple post-processing
    decoded_preds, decoded_labels = postprocess_text(decoded_preds, decoded_labels)

    result = metric.compute(predictions=decoded_preds, references=decoded_labels)
    result = {"bleu": result["score"]}

    prediction_lens = [np.count_nonzero(pred != tokenizer.pad_token_id) for pred in preds]
    result["gen_len"] = np.mean(prediction_lens)
    result = {k: round(v, 4) for k, v in result.items()}
    return result


trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model,
    args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets['train'],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets['test'],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)
trainer.train()

model_dir = './models/'
trainer.save_model(model_dir)
```

The code above is taken from this [Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/translation.ipynb#scrollTo=IreSlFmlIrIm). After the training, I can see the trained model is saved to the folder `models` and the metric is calculated. Now I want to load the trained model and do the prediction on a new dataset, here is what I tried:

```
dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files='data/training_data.csv')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)

# Tokenize the test dataset
tokenized_datasets = train_test.map(preprocess_function_v2, batched=True)
test_dataset = tokenized_datasets['test']
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained('models')
model(test_dataset)
```

It threw the following error:

```
*** AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'size'
```

I tried the `evaluate()` function as well, but it said:

```
*** torch.nn.modules.module.ModuleAttributeError: 'MarianMTModel' object has no attribute 'evaluate'
```

And the function `eval` only prints the configuration of the model.
What is the proper way to evaluate the performance of the trained model on a new dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the prediction can be produced using the following code:

```
inputs = tokenizer(
        questions,
        max_length=max_input_length,
        truncation=True,
        return_tensors='pt',
        padding=True).to('cuda')
translation = model.generate(**inputs)
```